# How to extract cloud points from the RealSense cameras?

Tags: 3d, intel, point-cloud-library, realsense

I am working with an Intel® [RealSense](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/realsense-3d-camera.html)™ device and the RSSDK.
 I also started looking at the [PCL](http://pointclouds.org) library.
The point cloud object tracking is somehow hidden below the MetaioTrackerToolbox.
I would like to get real time data clouds points from the RealSense cameras and use them with the PCL library. Does anyone know how to extract cloud points from the RealSense cameras to be used with the PCL library (I just found [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/perpetual-computing-generating-3d-from-depth-data), but it needs to be ported to RSSDK)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am working on a PCL grabber for RealSense cameras. Preliminary version is available in [my GitHub repository](https://github.com/taketwo/rs). There are a few issues, most important being that the memory leaks when grabbing colored point clouds (however this is due to a bug in RealSense SDK rather than in my code). As soon as that is fixed on the Intel side and once I polish the code it will be included in mainstream PCL.

**EDIT:** all the issues were solved and the grabber was merged into PCL.

Comment: Are you using the deprecated RealSense SDK or the libsense from the github ?

Comment: The referenced project was using the deprecated RealSense SDK. For newer cameras you may want to give a try to [this pull request](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/pull/2214).